# Have our needs changed?

Tags: qualia

With our evolving civilization, it is fairly easy to show that we act in the world in more complex ways on a daily basis; the world is more complex.

Have our real needs changed?

Have our felt needs changed or, are they just new applications of existing needs?

i.e. some examples of things that may be needs: self-validation, company (absence of aloneness), communication, education, safety, shelter, food, water.

Depending upon any answer, it may be further enquired whether our needs will change in the future?

Comment: Why the downvote? No comment?

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with another question:
Who are you, and who are we?

In order to answer whether your needs or our needs have changed, you need an answer to this question.

It soon becomes obvious that it's a very tricky one.
If you assume that you are your (=a) body, you would consequently conclude that the needs of your (=that) body are your needs. If you assume you are your brain and your thoughts, you would consequently assume that the needs of that brain and those thoughts are your needs. If you assume you are you as part of a family or a country or a religious group, you'd assume that their needs are yours. And so on.

While these assumptions are valid in that they can't be disproven, it should be noted that they collide with a common feeling or inner certainty of many people that there is something about them that doesn't die when the body dies or their family or their country. They feel there's something eternal or at least transcendental.

To cut a long story short: Unless you have a real experience of "you" in its truest form, all concepts of "you" are just a more or less arbitrary identification with something. This should be logical. And the weirdest thing is: There is not even a guarantee that the thing you're identified with exists at all.

Asking whether needs have changed in this context is asking if our bodies are changing, our brains are changing, our thoughts are changing, our psychology is changing, our emotions are changing, our hearts are changing.

While this is certainly the case to some degree, those changes are minute in the light of the huge amount of time humanity has existed so far. The only thing that is really changing and often evolving is our consciousness. For example today many of us appreciate the emotions and rights of animals and the need for protecting nature where our forefathers would just have laughed, or we move towards seeing other countries as neighbors and friends rather than enemies and competitors. It's a slow development, but it's happening steadily. This is an evolution in consciousness. It does not change our needs, but it changes the way we deal with them.

Consciousness is the source and the distillate of all identification or lack thereof. So does consciousness have any needs?

I would say if you reach the point where that question does not make any sense to you, you've gotten an idea of what I'm trying to say.

PS: I'm aware I'm answering the question on a level that you did not have in mind at all. Sorry for that. It's just the only answer I have right now.

Comment: A refreshing answer.